# Meaning of $f$ being a function on $\text{Spec}(A)$

Tags: sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $(\text{Spec}(A),\mathcal{O}_X)$ be an affine scheme. We say that $f\in A$ is a function on $\text{Spec}(A)$ by having for $[\mathfrak{p}]\in\text{Spec}(A)$ taken to $f([\mathfrak{p}])=\overline{f}\in A/\mathfrak{p}$ (meaning $f{\mod \mathfrak{p}})$.

Then we can see that $f:\text{Spec}(A)\to \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}(A)} A/\mathfrak{p}$, later this is meant to be $f:\text{Spec}(A)\to \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}(A)} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ right? So how do I bridge this gap? How do I relate $A/\mathfrak{p}$ to this localisation (in regard to functions and global sections)?

> How do I think of a function $f$ on the spectrum as a global section?

Comment: Let $U\subset \text{Spec}(A)$ be an open subset. Do I take it that $f\in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ can only be evaluated at points in $U$? I.e. we can only map it to quotients by the prime ideals which are in $U$?

Comment: Yes, only at points of $U$, but not in the quotients $A/p$ but in the localization $A_p$ - contrary to what I just wrote in my answer (which doesn't include anything wrong though)! The confusion (on my end) was what you meant by evaluated - there are two different choices as your question mentions. The one you mean when talking about $\Gamma(U, O_X)$ is where you look at the image in $A_p$. Take for example $X=Spec(\mathbb{Q}[x]/x^2)$ which has only one point, but the global sections are $\mathbb{Q}[x]/x^2$ while the "value" of $f=a+bx$ at the unique point $x=0$ is $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A/\mathfrak{p}$ is a domain, and its fraction field is isomorphic to $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$, which is also called the residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$.
The germ of the element $f$ takes values in $A_\mathfrak{p}$, but when thinking of $f$ as a function, the value  of $f(\mathfrak{p})$ is the image of $f$ in the residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$ (or as you said $A/\mathfrak{p}$).

You can also  think of $f$ as a section of the 'espace etale' (or something), which is basically like you said where you collect all the stalks together. To get what most people call the value at $\mathfrak{p}$ though, you have to mod out by $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$.

Given an element $f \in \mathfrak{p}$, - where one would say $f$ vanishes at $\mathfrak{p}$ - note that $f(\mathfrak{p})=0$ in the first interpretation (image of $f$ in $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$) but often/usually $f$ is nonzero in $A_\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Sorry my question was slightly unclear I think (I edited it)

Comment: On second thought, perhaps it was clear and I didn't understand your answer. So $f$ takes a point $p$ to $f\pmod{p}$ and then we just include into the residue field $A/p \to A_p/pA_p$.

Comment: you raise a good point, I was once confused about this myself. Once you are in $A/p$ that is enough since  $A/p$ injects into its fraction field so you can take the value in $A/p$ or $Frac(A/p)$. But while we often look at image of $f$ in $A_p$, to say $f$ vanishes at $p$ is not equivalent to $f=0$ in $A_p$.